# Does mutex tell processor not to interrupt thread?

Tags: multithreading, mutex

I was thinking about this when using mutex.

If you lock the thread with mutex for instance

```
m.lock();
a += b;
m.unlock();
```

What happens when the the two threads collide?
Is it like:

1) by locking thread A tells CPU that this must be executed uninterrupted until unlock
and while the a += b statement is happening context switch never occurs.

2) thread A locks, while doing the a += b statement context switch happens, thread B sees that its locked, yelds control and everything is back to A which finishes a += b; operation and unlocks access?

If it's case 2 after all, is there a way to tell CPU that certain parts of the code shall never be interrupted by context switch?

Comment: No. It stops any other thread from acquiring a lock on `m`, until the owning thread releases it.

Comment: Targetting C++, I don't know if this thing is platform/hardware dependant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is 2, and there is no direct way to say that code must run to completion without a context switch. You could probably get close by bumping the execution priority of the thread but such shenanigans are usually frowned upon and suggest a bad design.

Answer (score 0):

Both flavors of mutexes exist, but the first kind is used only in privileged programs (O/S kernel, hardware drivers). User is given only second kind, otherwise a user program could hang the whole system.